# How many odd numbers can be formed using the digits $0, 4, 5, 7$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many odd numbers can be formed using digits $0,4,5,7$.
I am getting answer $12$ but the actual answer is $14$.

Comment: I prefer the answer $22$, since you don't specify that all digits must be used each time. But I don't see any way that $14$ is correct..

Comment: I'd say infinity, since you can form $7$, $57$, $557$, $5557$, etc.

Comment: I got it, the correct answer as posted by Jordan is ${2 \choose 1}$ for the last digit, ${2 \choose 1}$ for the first digit, ${2 \choose 1}$ for the 2nd digit and then remains only one digit so no choices, that makes $8$

Comment: I get  4057, 4075, 4507, 4705, 5047, 5407, 7045, 7405,

405, 407, 457,507, 547, 705, 745, 
45, 47, 57, 75

5, 7

Comment: @Vikram there isn't a definite correct answer, due to ambiguity in the question. The viable options are 22, 12, 8 and "unlimited" .

Answer (score 4):

Suppose the number has to be of $n$ digits. Then the last digit has to be $5$ or $7$. Hence the solution is 
$$
4^{n-1} \cdot 2=2^{2n-1}.
$$
If the number has at most $n$ digits then the answer is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n2^{2i-1}=2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}4^i=\frac{2}{3}(4^n-1).
$$

---

Probably the correct interpretation:

We have to use exactly one each digit $0,4,5,7$. Then the last digit can be $5$ or $7$. The other can be chosen in $3!$ ways. Therefore the answer $2\cdot 3!=12$.

[Moreover, if we add the number has to have exactly $4$ digits (i.e. it doesn't start with $0$), then the answer would be $8$]

Ps. I still don't get why it could be $14$ :P

Answer (score 0):

There are 24 permutations of the digits, six each starting with 0, 4, 5 and 7. Four digit numbers don't start with a 0, leaving 3 times 6 permutations. If the first digit is 5 or 7 then we remove the two numbers ending in 4, so 3x6 - 2x2 = 14.